# ¿Para que sirve la línea @Override en java?

Tags: java

Disculpen soy nuevo en **java**, *he buscado respuestas en internet*, pero en todos lados hablan con un lenguaje muy complicado, alguien podria explicarlo de modo que mi abuelita lo entendiera?

Gracias.

Comment: En Java se trabaja con clases y estas heredan sus métodos a otras clases, @override se coloca delante un método heredado para sobrecargar (modificar) su comportamiento original

Comment: @Override Permite sobrescribir un método al momento que se hereda de una Interface en Java. Esta anotación es opcional.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> ¿Para que sirve la línea @Override en java?

Para nada. El uso de la anotación `@Override` es opcional.

Para lo único que realmente sirve es a modo de documentación:

- Un método marcado con `@Override` debería estar sobreescribiendo un método de alguna clase padre
- Si esto no es así, el compilador de java generará un error

Ejemplo:

```
class Base {
    public void metodoA() {
        System.out.println("Base A");
    }
}

class Hija extends Base {
    public void metodoA() {
        System.out.println("Hija A");
    }
    //@Override
    public void metodoB() {
        System.out.println("Hija B");
    }
}
```

El `metodoA()` de `Hija` si sobreescribe al `metodoA()` de `Base`, a pesar de no estar anotada con `@Override`

Sin embargo si se coloca `@Override` a un método que no sobrescribe nada, el compilador arroja un error:

> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: ¿Para **nada**? Si no sirve para nada, no existiría. Deberías retractarte de esa afirmación, `@Override` sirve **para mucho**, y en algunos contextos, **no es lo mismo usarlo que no usarlo**.

Comment: @A.Cedano es solo una afirmación corta para el contexto de la pregunta, en la misma respuesta pongo para que sirve. Esa anotacion es solo una herramienta de compilacion que a un programador que quiere comprender el funcionamiento de un codigo no le deberia interesar, porque efectivamente no hace nada.

Answer (score 31):

A pesar de que muchos te han dado una respuesta, me decidí a darte la mía ya que considero que ninguna de las anteriores es del todo correcta.

La anotación `@Override` simplemente se utiliza, para forzar al compilador a comprobar en tiempo de compilación que estás sobrescribiendo correctamente un método, y de este modo evitar errores en tiempo de ejecución, los cuales serían mucho más difíciles de detectar.

Por ejemplo, si fueras a sobrescribir el método `toString()` de la clase `Object` y lo haces de este modo:

```
public class MiClase {

    public String ToString() {
        return "Hola, esta es MiClase";
    }
}
```

realmente no estás sobrescribiendo el método, sino creando uno nuevo, ya que el nombre correcto comienza con minúscula y no con mayúscula. Por lo tanto, si luego en tu programa intentas obtener el `String` correspondiente de una instancia de `MiClase`, intentarías hacer esto, por ejemplo:

```
System.out.println(instanciaMiClase.toString());
```

obteniendo una salida como esta: `MiClase@55b7a4e0`, ya que se está llamando al método de la clase padre (que en este caso es Object). Pero si por el contrario le agregas la anotación:

```
public class MiClase {

    @Override
    public String ToString() {
        return "Hola, esta es MiClase";
    }
}
```

el compilador te va a avisar que tienes un problema con un mensaje de error como este: "Method does not override method from its superclass".

Por eso es que existe dicha anotación, para poder detectar en tiempo de compilación que no estás cumpliendo con los requisitos para sobrescribir un método.

Mi recomendación es que siempre pongas dicha anotación en los métodos que vayas a sobrescribir, te va a ahorrar muchos problemas.

Comment: Esta es realmente la única respuesta justa y totalmente correcta. Gracias!

Answer (score 7):

Es la capacidad que tiene una clase que hereda de poder modificar los métodos de su clase padre, por ejemplo:

```
public class Auto{
           
  public String modelo;
 
  public void manejar()
   {
    System.out.println("Manejar un vehículo");
   }
}
```

ahora sobreescribimos el método manejar, para que siga existiendo en la clase hija pero tenga distinto comportamiento

```
class Moto extends Auto
{
     @Override
     public void manejar()
     {
        System.out.println("Manejando mi primer motocicleta");
     }
}
```

Ahora si por ejemplo queremos acceder a los métodos de dicha clase debería ser así:

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Movil one = new Auto();  
      Movil two = new Moto();  

      one.manejar();   
      two.manejar();  
   }
}
```

**USO DE OVERRIDE**
En resumidas cuentas hacer override, permite a un método sobreescribir o modificar la declaración de un método en una clase superior

[**Fuente de consulta**](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

es muy simple, colocas `@Override` cuando vas a sobrescribir un método de una clase al hacer herencia, te pongo un ejemplo:

Si tengo la clase `mascota`con la función `correr()`:

```
public class mascota{

    private String nombre;
    private int energia;

    public String correr() {
        energia--;
        System.out.println("Energia: " + energia);
    }
}
```

luego creo la clase `perro` que va a heredar a la clase `mascota`, suponiendo que los perros gastan mas energía al correr entonces modificamos la función `correr()` con `@Override`:

```
public class perro extends mascota{

    @Override
    public String correr() {
        energia=energia-2;
        System.out.println("Energia: " + energia);
    }
}
```

En pocas palabras `@Override`permite que puedas reescribir la función ya antes definida de la clase anterior en tu nueva clase. Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta más simple es la que viene en la misma documentación, que traducida dice algo así:

Al hacer un método redefinible, podrías querer usar la anotación @Override que le dice al compilador que **pretendes redefinir siempre un método de la superclase**. Y si por alguna razón, el compilador detecta que el método no existe en alguna de las superclases generará un error.

Ese error te servirá para indicarte que se te olvidó hacerle una funcionalidad necesaria, por ello cuando trabajes con programadores novatos será de mucha ayuda ponerla para ayudarlos con un error que les indique que no cumplen con los requisitos mínimos que pusiste en tu interfaz ayudándoles a saber por ejemplo que:

- escribieron mal el nombre del método de la clase padre
- no pusieron un método que era necesario
- están usando una clase incorrecta que se llama igual
- quieren heredar un método que no existe en la clase padre

Fuente: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 0):

La anotación **`@Override`** en Java es utilizada para:

> Indicar la sobre escritura de un método.

Un ejemplo sería:

Cuando se crea una interface para la implementación de un objeto en una clase, esta permite sobre escribir la el comportamiento, funcionalidad del método en la clase que se implementa la interfase.

Answer (score -2):

[@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) es una anotaciones. Las anotaciones son metadatos que lee la JVM (Java Virtual Machine) para saber como procesar el código.

Para entender como funcionan las anotaciones primero tienes que entender como funcionan los metadatos. Los metadatos son datos que tienen información sobre otros datos, esta información la utiliza un programa para saber como utilizar ésos datos. Por ejemplo, en un archivo de audio un reproductor utiliza su formato para saber como reproducirlo, en este caso el metadato es el formato.

La JVM utiliza las anotaciones para decidir como procesar el código. La JVM procesa de manera diferente el código con anotaciones.

Un método sobrescrito no tiene porque llevar la anotación `@Override` de manera obligatoria, un método sobrescrito sin ella funcionara de todos modos. La anotación `@Override` se utiliza para asegurarse de que la JVM sobrescriba el método de manera adecuada. Es como si le dijeras a la JVM "oye, no te olvides de sobreescribir este método correctamente".

Ahora bien, no solo la JVM utiliza anotaciones. Cualquier programa, librería, framework, etc... que procese el código de un programa puede utilizar anotaciones; como es el caso del framework Spring que utiliza sus propias anotaciones para procesar el código.

Un desarrollador común no tiene porque preocuparse de como implementar anotaciones, solo tiene que saber para que las utiliza el programa que procesa su código. El implementar anotaciones es algo mas complejo y hay que entender sobre reflexión y otros temas complicados.

Para saber para que un programa utiliza sus anotaciones consulte la documentación de esa anotación. Por ejemplo, la anotación [@NonNull](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checkers-manual.html#nullness-checker) la utiliza un framework en Java para evitar que los argumentos de un método sean nulos, en caso de que estos sean nulos, el framework lanza una excepción en tiempo de compilación.

Para saber más sobre anotaciones consulta el siguiente articulo en la documentación oficial de Java.

[Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912), ya que la JVM no procesa de manera diferente el código con anotaciones, a menos que un procesador de anotaciones le diga como procesar la anotación específica en cuestión, si bien cuando salió @Override la comunidad lo consideraba como un metadato, tenía además la capacidad de agregar un nuevo error en tiempo de compilación