# ¿Porque me da error en esta clase abstracta de Java?

Tags: java

```
package poo;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Uso_Persona {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Persona[] lasPersonas = new Persona[2];

        lasPersonas[0] = new Empleado2("Luis Conde", 50000, 2009, 02, 25);
        lasPersonas[1] = new Alumno("Ana Lopez", "Biológicas");

        for (Persona p: lasPersonas) {

            System.out.println(p.dameNombre() + ", " + p.dameDescripcion());

        }

    }

}

abstract class Persona{

    public Persona(String nom) {

        nombre = nom;

    }

    public String dameNombre() {

        return nombre;

    }

    public abstract String dameDescripcion();

    private String nombre;

}

class Empleado2 extends Persona{

    public Empleado2(String nom, double sue, int agno, int mes, int dia) {

        super(nom);

        sueldo = sue;

        GregorianCalendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar(agno, mes-1, dia);

        altaContrato = calendario.getTime();

        ++IdSiguiente;

        Id = IdSiguiente;
    }

    public String dameDescipcion(){

        return "Este empleado tiene un Id= " + Id + " con un sueldo= "
                + sueldo;

    }

    public double dameSueldo() { // getter

        return sueldo;

    }

    public Date dameFechaContrato() {

        return altaContrato;

    }

    public void subeSueldo(double porcentaje) { // setter

        double aumento = sueldo*porcentaje/100;

        sueldo += aumento;

    }


    private double sueldo;

    private Date altaContrato;

    private static int IdSiguiente;

    private int Id;

}

class Alumno extends Persona{

    public Alumno(String nom, String car) {

        super(nom);

        carrera = car;

    }

    public String dameDescripcion() {

        return "Este alumno está estidiando la carrera de"+ carrera;

    }

    private String carrera;

}
```

El error es:

"*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type Empleado2 must implement the inherited abstract method Persona.dameDescripcion()*"

Pero como pueden ver el método abstracto al cual hace referencia está incluido.

Comment: Creo que la no debe ser cerrada, ya que describe un problema real en el que pueden incurrir muchos usuarios. Los problemas en las  firmas de los métodos que intentamos sobrescribir son muy frecuentes, y si dicho método no es abstracto, pues el compilador no avisa y tenemos comportamientos impredecibles en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se debe a que el nombre del método en `Empleado2` no coincide con el del padre. En `Empleado2` lo declaras como `dameDescipcion()`, si te das cuenta te falta una `r` entre la primera `c` y la `i` de la palabra descripcion. Esribe correctamente el nombre del método y listo.

Para evitar este tipo de errores, utiliza la anotación `@Override` la cual obliga en tiempo de compilación a comprobar que un método está sobrescribiendo a uno en su padre.

Mira mi respuesta a [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%C3%ADnea-override-en-java/156487#156487) donde explico un poco mejor el uso de `@Override`.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que el error de la pregunta ocurre en tiempo de compilación, ¿Cuál es la ventaja de usar @override o no usarlo en este caso?

Comment: El error de la pregunta ocurre en tiempo de compilación, pero no te indica que tú método (el cual estás escribiendo para sobrescribir uno en el padre) tienen un problema en la firma, solo te marca un error a nivel de la clase que te indica que no estás sobrescribiendo el método en cuestión. Aquí es donde entra a jugar la anotación @Override, ya que fuerza al compilador a comprobar, que el método que anotaste, esté sobrescribiendo correctamente a uno en el padre (o alguna interfaz que implemente la clase).

Comment: Interesante. Entonces la ventaja es que ayuda a identificar más rápido qué método es el problemático en la clase que hereda. Me imagino que algunos IDEs mostrarán error incluso antes de compilar.

Comment: Efectivamente, te ayuda a detectar una sobrescritura incorrecta en tiempo de compilación. Lo de los IDEs no se si lo indiquen antes de compilar, recuerda que los principales IDEs para java realizan una compilación en tiempo real.