# Recibo errores al compilar error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Los errores se aprecian en estos archivos

**Accounts.java 2 errors**

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
```

**Categories.java 2 errors**

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
```

**Currencies.java 1 error**

```
error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
Tags.java 1 error
error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
```

**Transactions.java 1 error**

```
error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
```

**Users.java 1 error**

```
error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)
@Override public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) { return (Builder) 
 super.setBatchPath(batchPath); }
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Los errores se producen porque:

> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

1 - Estás intentando sobrescribir uno o varios métodos que no existen en la clase padre de tu clase. Para corregirlo asegúrate definir correctamente la clase de la cual hereda la tuya o las interfaces que implementa. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%C3%ADnea-override-en-java/156487#156487) puedes encontrar una explicación sobre el uso de `@Override` para que entiendas porqué el compilador te lanza esos errores.

> error: cannot find symbol method setBatchPath(String)

2 - Estás intentando acceder a un método de la clase padre (`super.setBatchPath(String)`) que al parecer no existe. Nuevamente, para corregisrlo asegúrate definir correctamente la clase de la cual hereda la tuya.