# ¿Debemos usar la anotación @Override de Java al implementar los métodos de una interfaz?

Tags: java

Tengo claro que **la anotación @Override se usa al sobreescribir métodos** heredados de forma explícita o implícita.

He visto en una de las respuestas a otra pregunta que la usaba en métodos que implementaba (procedentes de una interfaz). Me pareció que era correcto e hice una búsqueda para asegurarme. Sigo pensando que está mal, pero hay mucha controversia...

Parece que en Java 1.5 se prohibió hacer esto, en Java 1.6 se volvió a admitir, y depende del IDE te deja o no hacerlo, a mi *Netbeans 8.2 con la configuración por defecto* no me deja. Luego hay gente que defiende su uso para saber si a futuro hay modificaciones de las firmas de método en alguna de las interfaces (lo que me parece que no debería ocurrir y obedece a errores de diseño), en cuyo caso creo que hay que revisar las implementaciones, no esperar a que se queje el compilador...

¿entonces?

Pregunta relacionada: [¿Para que sirve la línea @Override en java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%C3%ADnea-override-en-java)

Comment: [Aquí, varias respuestas magistrales](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94361/5587982) donde podrás encontrar *ton bonheur* y formarte tu propio criterio.

Comment: @A. Cedano muchas gracias, creo que he leído una traducción de ese mismo hilo.

Comment: Se podría concluir que, cuando JDK obliga a usar `@Override` conviene usarlo y también siempre que no esté prohibido... por varios motivos expuestos: obligar a implementar métodos, evitar errores en futuras evoluciones del código, etc.