# Operaciones heredadas de Object en java

Tags: java

Mis dudas són:

- Que són operaciones heredadas de object?
- Cuales existen?
- Como y para que las implementaría?

Ya que estoy modelando un sistema Carcelario en Java para el cual tengo las clases Carcel,Sistema Penitenciario, Maxima y Minima Seguridad.

Al igual que algunas interfaces, pero en una parte dice que tengo que implementar las operaciones heredadas de object, no sé si eso se refiere a equals(), o esa es solo una de todas las operaciones heredadas.

Comment: creo que lo que deseas hacer es un [override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html), esto lo que define es "cambiar el comportamiento de una funcion/metodo", en un objeto Heredado
[wikipedia overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)
con relacion a `Object`, Object posee 11 metodos de los cuales 5 pueden ser Heredados [javadoc de Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) `equals()`, `clone()`, `hashcode()`, `toString()`, `finalize()`

Comment: Usualmente si se desea hacer override de un metodo de Object es sobre `toString()`,`equals()`,`hashcode()` y en menor medida `clone` y `finalize`

`toString()` por ejemplo por defector retorna `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` pero puedes cambiar este comportamiento para que retorne algo mas "significativo"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

la respuesta de esta pregunta va de la mano de la comprensión de los conceptos de Herencia, por tanto en caso de ser necesario hacer referencia al tutorial de Oracle con relación a Herencia [tutorial de Herencia de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) y [Polimorfismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_(inform%C3%A1tica))

> Que son operaciones heredadas de object?

recordemos que **toda** clase en java Hereda de `java.lang.Object`(a menos que explícitamente herede de otra clase) por tanto cuando se define una clase por ejemplo 
`class Carcel` es lo mismo que decir `class Carcel extends java.lang.Object` el `extends java.lang.Object` es implícito en la primera definición.

[image: mapa de herencias en java]

(imagen de:[tutorial de Herencia de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) )

con lo anterior claro 
todo atributo(variable) & comportamiento(método) es heredado desde la clase `Object` hacia la Clase `Carcel` (dado a que `Object` no posee atributos `Carcel` por tanto no hereda atributos, pero si comportamientos)

> Cuales existen?

una clase que hereda de Object hereda sus comportamientos(metodos):

```
/*se hereda, pero no se pueden modificar*/
public final native Class<?> getClass();
public final native void notify();
public final native void notifyAll();
public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException;
public final void wait(long timeout, int nanos) throws InterruptedException
public final void wait() throws InterruptedException
/*modificables*/
public native int hashCode();
public boolean equals(Object obj)
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
public String toString()
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
```

referencia [Object Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

los métodos que tienen la palabra clave `final` no son *overridable(modificables)* [mas sobre final methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) (nota: la palabra clave `final` utilizada en un atributo(variable) tiene un significado diferente que en un método, y cuando se utilizan en una clase significa que la clase no puede ser heredada)

por tanto toda clase puede modificar (con ciertas excepciones*(ver nota #1)) el comportamiento de `hashCode()`,`equals(Object obj)`,`clone()`,`toString()`,`finalize()`

> Como y para que las implementaría?

separemos esta pregunta en 2 partes:

> Como

para modificar el comportamiento de cualquiera de estos métodos simplemente se redefine el método (utilizando la misma firma que en `Object` por ejemplo:

```
class Carcel {
    String nombre; 
    //@Override es opcional, pero ayuda para que el IDE/compilador detecte algun problema de herencia
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Carcel %s",nombre);
    } 
}
```

[para que sirve @Override](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%C3%ADnea-override-en-java)

> para que las implementaría?

`hashCode()` -> este método "calcula el `Hash`" del objeto, este método usualmente se utiliza para determinar "un valor único (Integer)" y "acomodar" los objetos cuando se deben acomodar en una Colección que utiliza ordenamiento por "buckets" (`HashMap`, `HashTable`, `HashSet`) ([referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563847/what-is-the-use-of-hashcode-in-java))

**para que:** tratar de mejorar el rendimiento del cálculo del Hash, de la mano de hacer "detección de duplicados" (evitar que existan duplicados en `HashMap`, `HashTable`, `HashSet`) se recomienda hacer `Override` a este método cuando se hace `Override` a `equals`

`equals(Object obj)` -> verifica si un objeto es "igual" a otro su implementación en Object es: `return (this == obj);` por ejemplo esto no sirve en String. por tanto, String hace `Override` a este método y hace una comparación del contenido del String.

**para que:** definir "que atributos" hacen al Objeto igual a otro. por ejemplo una `Carcel` es Igual a otra si: `Carcel1.name.equals(Carcel2.name)&&Carcel1.dirreccion.equals(Carcel2.dirreccion)` y de esta forma, si los demás atributos son diferentes la "Razón de igualdad" son esos 2 atributos.

`clone()` -> código nativo pero este método es utilizado para hacer "copias" del objeto en cuestión.

**para que:** definir un método en particular para crear "copias" puesto es el consenso general que usar "clone()" nativo puede producir problemas en general se sugiere evitar usar/o hacer `Override [por que evitar clone()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method/2326801#2326801)

`toString()` -> provee una representación en String del Objeto en cuestión. su implementación en Object es: `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

**para que:** para hacer que `toString()` retorne un valor más significativo que el nombre de la clase y su Valor hash. por ejemplo `Carcel.toString()` podría retornar algo más útil como por ejemplo: `return String.format("Carcel %s localizada en :%s",nombre,dirreccion);`

`finalize()` -> este metodo es llamado por el GC(Garbage Collector) y este es llamado cuando el Objeto "ya no tiene referencias vivas o utilizadas en algún hilo"

**para que:** se recomienda hacer `Override` a este método cuando se requiere o utilizan recursos que deben ser cerrados (por ejemplo Conexiones de Bases de datos o cuando se utiliza código nativo llamado por JNI/JNA)

***nota #1***
excepciones, las clases que Heredan `Object` Pueden hacer `Override` e estos métodos, pero a su vez puede hacer el método `final` por ejemplo:

```
class Carcel {
    String nombre; 
    //@Override es opcional, pero ayuda para que el IDE/compilador detecte algún problema de herencia
    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return String.format("Carcel %s",nombre);
    } 
}
```

al `public final String toString()` ser `final` si otra clase trata de hacer `Override` dará error: 
[image: error en final override]