# Duda acerca de los Metodos en Java

Tags: java

Soy novato en Java, y más o menos entiendo el tema de los métodos, específicamente la pregunta es acerca de los métodos heredados/implementados de alguna clase/interfaz.

¿Cómo es posible sobrescribir un método de una interfaz de la API, sin dañar su funcionamiento y que además funcione sin llamar al método `super()`?
¿Por qué el programa compila adecuadamente si el método no es llamado en el constructor de la clase LaminaLibre (JPanel)?

[El programa compila bien, no tiene ningún error; la pregunta va más orientada al comportamiento de los métodos sobrescritos de la API de Java.]

```
  class LaminaLibre extends JPanel{
    public LaminaLibre() {
        setLayout(new EnColumnas());
    
        JLabel nombre= new JLabel("Nombre: ");
        JLabel apellido= new JLabel("Apellido: ");
        JLabel edad= new JLabel("Edad: ");
        
        JTextField c_nombre= new JTextField();
        JTextField c_apellido=new JTextField();
        JTextField c_edad=new JTextField();
        
        
        add(nombre);
        add(c_nombre);
        add(apellido);
        add(c_apellido);
        add(edad);
        add(c_edad);
    }
}

    class EnColumnas implements LayoutManager{     //AQUI EMPIEZA VIDEO 119

    
    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        
        
    }

    
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        
    }

    
    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        
        return null;
    }

    
    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        
        return null;
    }

    public void layoutContainer(Container micontenedor) {
        int contador=0;
        int n=micontenedor.getComponentCount();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            contador++;
            Component c=micontenedor.getComponent(i);
            c.setBounds(x, y, 100, 20);
            x+=100;
            if(contador%2==0) {
                x=20;
                y+=40;
            }
        }
    }
private int x=20;
private int y=20;
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *"Como es posible"*?

Comment: Me referia al "Por que" de este funcionamiento. Es posible sobreescribir un metodo heredado de una clase/interfaz de la api de Java  sin danar su funcionamiento? No haria falta llamar al metodo super() para invocar al metodo heredado de la clase/interfaz padre para que este hiciera su trabajo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a @Override, puedes ver la informacion de esta anotacion en [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%C3%ADnea-override-en-java/156457)