# Anotar el método toString() con @Override o no y usar this o no en el contexto de una clase Java, ¿hay algo definitivo sobre esto?

Tags: java, poo, buenas-prácticas

Es una duda que tengo hace tiempo y no encuentro nada en concreto al respecto.

En una clase cualquiera, si quiero sobre-escribir el método `toString()`, y usar las propiedades de la clase.

Me funciona si anoto el método con `@Override` y si uso `this`:

```
@Override
public String toString () 
{
    return String.format("Nombre: %s, Apellido: %s",this.firstName,this.lastName);
}
```

Y si no anoto y/o no uso `this`, también funciona:

```
public String toString () 
{
    return String.format("Nombre: %s, Apellido: %s",firstName,lastName);
}
```

Son dos (x2) preguntas en una:

- ¿Se debe anotar o no con `@Override`?, ¿por qué sí o por qué no? ¿A qué se debe que funcione de ambas formas?
- ¿Se debe usar `this` o no?, ¿por qué sí o por qué no? ¿A qué se debe que funcione de ambas formas?

He estado investigando sobre esto pero no encuentro nada en concreto. Quiero saber si hay alguna respuesta, documentación a práctica establecida que defina lo que se debe hacer en estos casos, para dar uniformidad a mi código ya que a veces lo uso o lo dejo de usar, dado que funciona de ambas formas.

Comment: Cuando revisas código con el que no estas familiarizado y ves una variable en uso, te preguntas: ¿Será local, será argumento ó será miembro de clase?

Comment: Si quieres conocer para que sirve/se usa la anotación `@Override` puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%c3%adnea-override-en-java/156487#156487) a la pregunta [¿Para que sirve la línea @Override en java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%C3%ADnea-override-en-java/).

Answer (score 4):

## @Override

> ¿Se debe anotar o no con `@Override`?, ¿por qué sí o por qué no? ¿A qué se debe que funcione de ambas formas?

Efectivamente, funciona de ambas maneras. La anotación `@Override` **ayuda a los desarrolladores** para saber a simple vista que **hay un método de una clase principal que ha sido anulado por una clase secundaria**. En este caso, el método `.toString()` de la clase `String`.

## this

> ¿Se debe usar this o no?, ¿por qué sí o por qué no? ¿A qué se debe que funcione de ambas formas?

`this` se utiliza para indicar específicamente que se usa **la variable de instancia en lugar de la variable estática o local**. Es decir:

```
public class Persona {

    private final String nombre;

    public Persona(String nombre) {
        // como podríamos inicializar el valor nombre usando el parámetro?
        // no podemos hacer: nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior, queremos asignar el miembro de campo usando el valor del parámetro. Dado que comparten el mismo nombre, **necesitamos una forma de distinguir entre el campo y el parámetro. `this` nos permite acceder a los miembros de esta instancia, incluido el campo**.

```
public class Persona {
    private final String nombre;

    public Persona(String nombre) {
        this.nombre= nombre;
    }
}
```

Por lo tanto no podríamos decir que en este caso en particular, funciona de todas maneras. En caso de no usar `this`, estamos obligados a ponerle un nombre distinto a las dos variables.

En cuanto al ejemplo que brindaste, se podría considerar que el `@Override` es una buena práctica, y con el `this` estás especificando que te refieres a la variable de instancia. En caso de que en un futuro tengas un método así:

```
public String toString (String firstName, String lastName) 
{
    return String.format("Nombre: %s, Apellido: %s",this.firstName,this.lastName);
}
```

Le estás indicando al compilador que te refieres a la variable de instancia y no a los que estás recibiendo como parámetros: `(String firstName, String lastName)`

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Simplemente quisiera añadir que el uso de `@Override` es considerado buena práctica no solo porque ayuda a ver que el método está sobreescribiendo uno del padre, si no que también ayuda a detectar *si has escrito mal un método*, dado que si pones `@Override public String toStirng()` (véase que la R está en donde no toca), casi todos los IDE te darán un warning porque tu método no sobreescribe un método del padre! Sin embargo el método en si sería perfectamente válido y funcional

Answer (score 1):

Para responder esta pregunta hay que recordar varios conceptos de POO y Java.

**¿Por qué funciona si pongo u omito** [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)**?**

Las palabras reservadas [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) o [`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) se utilizan para hacer referencia a un contexto:

- `this`: Hace referencia al objeto actual
- `super`: Hace referencia a la super-clase (padre)

Te pongo un ejemplo conjuntando lo anterior.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject("María", (byte) 10, "Nicolo", (byte) 50);
        System.out.println(customObject.toString());
        customObject.printExample("Fido", (byte) 2);

        
    }

    private static class CustomFather {
        public final String name;
        public final byte age;

        public CustomFather(String name, byte age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    private static class CustomObject extends CustomFather{

        public String name;
        public byte age;

        public CustomObject(String name, byte age, String father, byte father_age) {
            super(father, father_age);
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Nombre: " + name + ", Edad: " + age;
        }
        
        public void printExample(String name, byte age) {

            System.out.println("Parameters: " + name + ", " + age);
            System.out.println("CustomObject: " + this.name + ", " + this.age);
            System.out.println("CustomFather: " + super.name + ", " + super.age);
            
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
// Del método toString
Nombre: María, Edad: 10

// Del método printExample
Parameters: Fido, 2
CustomObject: María, 10
CustomFather: Nicolo, 50
```

Podemos ver que en las clases anteriores:

- **CustomObject** hereda de **CustomFather**
- En el método `toString`no necesito hacer uso de `this`, ¿Entonces por qué lo uso en `printExample`?

La respuesta es el **shadowing**

El shadowing sucede cuando entras en un subcontexto donde una o más variables del contexto padre se llaman igual.

Fíjate en este ejemplo:

```java
public void printExample(String name, byte age){
    System.out.println("Parameters: " + name + ", " + age);
    System.out.println("Parameters: " + this.name + ", " + this.age);
    System.out.println("CustomFather: " + super.name + ", " + super.age);
}
```

El método recibe parámetros con los mismos nombres que las variables del objeto, el objeto tiene las mismas variables que el padre.

Por ello mismo para acceder a todos los datos necesito:

1. Hacer omisión del `this`: para saber que me refiero a las variables que recibo como parámetros
2. Hacer uso del `this`: para saber que me refiero a las propiedades del objeto
3. Hacer uso del `super`: para saber que me refiero a las propiedades del objeto padre

**¿Por qué se usa el **[`@override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)**?**

> La capacidad de una subclase de sobrescribir un método permite que una clase herede de una superclase cuyo comportamiento sea "lo suficientemente parecido" y luego modifique el comportamiento según sea necesario. El método de reemplazo tiene el mismo nombre, número y tipo de parámetros y tipo de retorno que el método que reemplaza. Un método reemplazado también puede devolver un subtipo del tipo devuelto por el método reemplazado. Este subtipo se denomina tipo de retorno covariante.

En pocas palabras, ese método ya existe en la clase [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) y para modificar su comportamiento debemos hacer uso de la etiqueta [`@override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

**EDIT: Más acerca del uso de Override**

Gracias a que se pueden realizar estas prácticas en POO, se puede hablar de polimorfismo.

Personalmente me gusta mucho la programación orientada a objetos, pues los puedes ver como biología. así que la definición de polimorfismo según la [National Human Genome Research Institute](https://www.genome.gov/es/genetics-glossary/Polimorfismo):

> El polimorfismo implica una de dos o más variantes de una secuencia particular de ADN

Por lo cual podemos heredar métodos de una clase, o implementar métodos de una interfaz y adecuarlos para cada Objeto hijo.

Pondré un ejemplo con una clase abstracta.

```java
public abstract class Worker {

    protected int id_worker;
    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    protected String job;
    protected int labor_old;

    public Worker(int id_worker, String name, int age, String job, int labor_old) {
        this.id_worker = id_worker;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.job = job;
        this.labor_old = labor_old;
    }

    protected void introduceTheirSelf(){
        System.out.print("Me llamo " + this.name + ". ");
        System.out.print("Tengo " + age + " años y trabajo desde ");
        System.out.print("hace " + labor_old + " años ");
        System.out.println("y trabajo como " + this.job);
    }

    protected abstract void work();
    protected abstract void specialize();
}
```

Del trabajador hereda el **Ingeniero**

```java
public class Engineer extends Worker{

    public Engineer(int id_worker, String name, int age, String job, int labor_old) {
        super(id_worker, name, age, job, labor_old);
    }

    @Override
    protected void work() {
        System.out.println("Trabajo diseñando robots");
    }

    @Override
    protected void specialize() {
        System.out.println("Me especializaré en inteligencia artificial");
    }
}
```

Del trabajador también hereda el **doctor**

```java
public class Doctor extends Worker{

    private final static String studies = "oncología";
    private final static String school = "Harvard";

    protected Doctor(int id_worker, String name, int age, String job, int labor_old) {
        super(id_worker, name, age, job, labor_old);
    }

    @Override
    protected void introduceTheirSelf(){
        System.out.print("Me llamo " + this.name + ". ");
        System.out.print("Tengo " + age + " años y trabajo desde");
        System.out.print(". Estudié " + studies + " en " + school);
        System.out.println(" y trabajo como " + this.job);
    }

    @Override
    protected void work() {
        System.out.println("Realizo cirugías y doy consultas");
    }

    @Override
    protected void specialize() {
        System.out.println("Me voy a especializar en neurocirugía");
    }
    
}
```

**Main.java**

```java
public class Objects {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Engineer engineer = new Engineer(1, "Pedro", 52, "diseñador de robots", 21);
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor(1, "María", 45, "Médico de un hospital", 20);

        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Especialización");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Doctor:");
        doctor.specialize();

        System.out.println("Ingeniero:");
        engineer.specialize();


        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Presentación");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Doctor:");
        doctor.introduceTheirSelf();

        System.out.println("Ingeniero:");
        engineer.introduceTheirSelf();


    }

}
```

**Output**

```
-------------------------------
Especialización
-------------------------------
Doctor:
Me voy a especializar en neurocirugía
Ingeniero:
Me especializaré en inteligencia artificial
-------------------------------
Presentación
-------------------------------
Doctor:
Me llamo María. Tengo 45 años y trabajo desde. Estudié oncología en Harvard y trabajo como Médico de un hospital
Ingeniero:
Me llamo Pedro. Tengo 52 años y trabajo desde hace 31 años y trabajo como diseñador de robots
```

Como vemos podemos ver el `@override` puede ser usado tanto para sobrescribir métodos abstractos como métodos no abstractos. Aunque como dice en la documentación, no podemos sobrescribir métodos estáticos, pues su propia naturaleza es contraria.