# No me devuelve nada en método ToString

Tags: java, visual-studio, poo, java-8

Estoy haciendo unas prácticas con objetos y al mencionar para que me muestre la información del objeto en el main no me devuelve nada, sin embargo el código no me da ningún error.

CLASE USUARIO:

```
class Usuario {

private String dni;
private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private ArrayList<Libro> prestado = new ArrayList<Libro>();

public Usuario(String dni, String n, String a) {

    this.dni = dni;
    this.nombre = n;
    this.apellidos = a;
    

}

public Usuario(Usuario x) {
    this.dni = x.dni;
    this.nombre = x.nombre;
    this.apellidos = x.apellidos;
    this.prestado = x.prestado;
}
public String mostraruser() {
    return "DNI: [" + dni + "] Nombre: " + nombre + ", Apellidos: " + apellidos;
}
```

Obviamente más abajo están los getter y setter pero no lo pongo para no llegar esto de código. El main sería el siguiente.

```
    Usuario u2 = new Usuario("x32321312d", "PEPE", "Diaz");
    Libro l1 = new Libro("1", "Pepito", "Diego Vergas", 222);
    ArrayList<Libro> rellenar = new ArrayList<>();
    rellenar.add(l1);
    u2.mostraruser();
```

Los sysout me funcionan pero al llamar a la funcion de mostraruser no me sale nada. ¿Alguna ayudita?

Comment: te falta imprimir `System.out.println(u2.mostraruser());`

Comment: Madre mía! Menuda tontería como se me había podido olvidar... Me estaba doliendo la cabeza ya.

Comment: Puedes renombrar la función `mostraruser` a `toString` así puedes imprimirlo por consola simplemente con `System.out.println(u2)`

Comment: @Mateo necesitaría la anotación override, no?

Comment: @Alfabravo como alguien que está acostumbrado a programar en C# si, pero la función `toString` en Java no está marcada como `virtual` así que no es necesario. Me tomé la libertad de probarlo sin y con `@Override`. En ambos casos funciona bien (incluso con polimorfismo)

Comment: @Mateo, en C# no se cómo funciona, pero en Java todos los métodos son virtuales a menos que indiques lo contrario. Respecto al uso del `@Override` [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156432/para-que-sirve-la-l%c3%adnea-override-en-java/156487#156487) puede ayudar a entender su uso.